# Does MVC in Visual Studio 2019 not create files automatically like 2015 does?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

For those that are already using visual studio 2019, does it not automatically create the identitymodels and accountviewmodels like 2015 does? or am I going about creating it in the wrong way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project, choose Add > New Scaffold Item > Identity and then choose which files you want to override, or choose all of them to make it like the older Visual Studio template.